# AngularJS : flotChart doesn't scroll well when the header is fixed

Tags: angularjs

am trying out a page with few piecharts drawn using flotchart in AngularJS. the header in this page is fixed and rest of the page is scrollable. But when the flotchart's pie charts scrolls, it goes over the header, and not below it.

[image]

can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You might use `z-index` CSS property to position your header div in front of those charts.